# PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'Rough.txt' -> 'CodewithGanesh.txt'

Tags: python

`os.rename("Rough.txt", "CodewithGanesh.txt")`

I closed all the opened process and still am getting the error:

> File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
> pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
> File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev_pydev_imps_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
> exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
> File "C:/Users/GANESH JADHAV/PycharmProjects/WUFeedsFileProcessing/venv/FeedProcessing.py", line 22, in 
> os.rename("Rough.txt", "CodewithGanesh.txt")
> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'Rough.txt' -> 'CodewithGanesh.txt'

Comment: Restart your PC

Answer (score 0):

Try a full system restart - could be an orphaned process running somewhere hard to find.